# mongo query is always returning as true

Tags: mongodb

New to mongo. Attempting to query the db and it always returns my console.log of 'this user exists' regardless of whether they really do or not. It makes it to the function in the login route as determined from my console.log. How can I fix it? Here is my code:

```
var checkCredentials = function(userName, password) {
    console.log('made it to checkCredentials()');
    User.find({
        "name" : userName.toLowerCase(),
        "password" : password
    }),
    function(error, user) {
        console.log('made it to function in login route');
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        if (userName.toLowerCase && typeof userName.toLowerCase && password && typeof password !== 'undefined') {
            console.log('this user exists');
        }
    }();
}
```

UPDATED CODE still is not working:

```
var checkCredentials = function(userName, password) {
    console.log('made it to checkCredentials()');
    User.findOne({
        "name" : userName.toLowerCase(),
        "password" : password
    }),
    function(error, user) {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
        console.log(user);
    }();
}
```

Comment: That's correct, what's the problem? The query resolves also if user doesn't exist, you aren't checking that.

Comment: Probably you need to check for the existence of `user`

Comment: @Michelem I am trying to determine if the user does exist based on the name value matching as well as the password value matching. It is always returning that the values match what is in the db although they really do not exist.

Comment: You are checking for the existence of the variables you are passing, that's obvious it passes. You should check for example if `userName.toLowerCase === user.name`

Comment: @Michelem - ok, that makes sense. I am now getting a TypeError: Cannot read property of 'name' in undefined.

Comment: So just check if `user` exists `if (user) {`

Comment: @Michelem - that isn't working either. And if I console.log(user) in the function it returns undefined.

Comment: Use `findOne` instead of `find` when looking up a single doc. The `user` callback parameter is an array with `find`, but the doc itself (or null) with `findOne`.

Comment: @JohnnyHK - thanks. I switched it to findOne but user is still showing as undefined. I will update my code on top to show you what I have.

Comment: It's not an error if the user doesn't exist. You need to check `if (user)` to see if it exists.

Comment: @JohnnyHK - I have tried if(user){ console.log('user exists');} but it doesn't let me know the user exists when the user does. Also, if I simply console.log(user) in the function it returns undefined always.

Answer (score 0):

This code ended up working. I don't know why it was not working originally. I ended up erasing it, retyping it, and it worked. Not sure what the issue was.

```
var checkCredentials = function(userName, password, res) {
    User.findOne({
        "name" : userName,
        "password" : password
    }, function(error, user) {
        if (error) {
            return handleError(error);
        } else if (user == null) {
            console.log('no match');
            res.send('noMatch');
        }
    });
}
```